# C++ difference between "char *" and "char * = new char[]"

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, heap-memory

So, if I want to declare an array of characters I can go this way

```
char a[2];
char * a ;
char * a = new char[2];
```

Ignoring the first declaration, the other two use pointers. As far as I know the third declaration is stored in heap and is freed using the delete operator . does the second declaration also hold the array in heap ? Does it mean that if something is stored in heap and not freed can be used anywhere in a file like a variable with file linkage ? I tried both third and second declaration in one function and then using the variable in another but it didn't work, why ? Are there any other differences between the second and third declarations ?

Comment: The second declaration does not allocate memory, so it does not "store" anything anywhere. It's just a dangling pointer and you shouldn't be using it before you assign some memory to it. Also, fixed-length arrays such as the first declaration are OK, but for all other purposes, you should really use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.

Comment: @MrLister so if I do something like char * a = "something" , is a stored in stack or heap ?

Comment: Ah, but then you _do_ initialise the pointer, see.

Comment: @nashmaniac: The pointer `a` is stored on the stack. The data pointed to by `a` ("something"): it depends where it was allocated. If you allocated it with `new`, then on the heap. If you used the `&` operator to get the address of a stack variable, then it is on the stack. If it is a string literal, then it is probably stored in the data segment, together with static variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the first case, `a[2]` stores 2 chars on the stack.
- In the second case, there is no allocation at all - `a` is an uninitialized
  pointer.
- In the third case, 2 chars are allocated on the heap.

You are right in thinking that heap allocated variables can be shared across your process, however, you will need to ensure that you pass the location of the allocated heap memory around - you do this e.g. by returning `a` from your method or function, or by increasing the scope of `a` e.g. to class scope.

`delete` will free heap allocations. In your case, `delete` should only be used in scenario 3, since in #1, stack variables are cleaned up when they go out of scope, and in #2, you haven't allocated any memory.

Because the above can easily lead to chaos during the transfer of ownership over the heap allocations, smart pointers such as `auto_ptr` or [boost's shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) can be used to make life simpler.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr / http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr for the `std::` ones.